# Why it doesn't show report on cucumber?

Tags: jenkins, nunit, cucumber, specflow

I want to show cucumber report on jenkins.It can work success.But it just show number of build.Nothing in the photos(it should have pie charts inside) and Feature Statistics is all zero, either.
And I tried to add `cucumber --format json -o cucumber.json` in my item. It would show `'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.` this message for me.And fail the build.What's wrong did I done?

Is I missing something or something wrong?

Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: is the installation directory to cucumber on the system path? have you tried specifying the full path to cucumber in your command like: `c:\path\to\cucumber --format json -o cucumber.json`

Comment: It work!thank you!But I got a new problem.I run 10 scenario but it just show 5 results on cucumber report.Why it will missing? And it will be same the result no matter what item I build.

Comment: It still show 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\cucumber --format json -o cucumber.json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.